# simple cURL request with RESTSharp

Tags: c#, curl, post, restsharp

I want to execute a simple cURL command with c#

```
curl https://doma.in/to/verify/license \
-d "produkt=test01" \
-d "key=123123123123" \
-X POST
```

What is what is the equivalent to C# or RESTSharp?
I tried this:

```
var client = new RestClient("https://doma.in");
var request = new RestRequest("/to/verify/license", Method.POST);
```

But I don't know how to translate this to RESTSharp:

```
-d "produkt=test01" \
-d "key=123123123123" \
-X POST
```

Manpage of cURL says '-d' is for send data but I can't find a send data tag for RESTSharp. How can I translate this code to c#? And how can I save the answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a model to hold the data to be posted and add it to the request.

```
//...

var body = new {
    produkt = "test01",
    key = "123123123123"
};

request.AddBody(body);
```

Check the [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/) site for documentation on how to use the library